# For loop with If and elif or else in python

Tags: python

Question 1:

Just tried to execute the program but i am getting syntax error

```
i=input('Enter the value of i')
for j in range(10):
    if i==j:
        print'The value of i is %d'%(i)
        elif i!=j:
            print'Please enter a valid value'
            else:
                print 'This is not a number'
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly and ask only one question per post.

Comment: If your code is really indented that way, that's the reason why you're getting the SyntaxError. `elif` and `else` should be aligned with `if`

Comment: `"i am getting syntax error"` - Actually looking at the error would be a *great* place to start with that one.  `"What is the difference between the below to codes"` - Line 1 in the first sample is moved to line 2 in the second.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini  i dont think so its indent issue.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the below two codes is that code one will ask for input once and then loop trying to compare, while code two will ask for input each loop (10x)...

Answer (score 0):

If your code is really indented as you put it here, the reason you are getting a syntax error is that your `elif` and `else` blocks are indented too far.  Another problem with your code is that `i` can be either equal or not equal to `j`.  There is no third option.  Another problem is that the first time it comes across a number that is not equal to the number typed, it will say that it is not a valid value.  Also, just saying "Please enter a valid value" will not make it so.  Here is a better version of your code:

```
i = None
while True:
    i = input("Enter the value of i")
    if i.isdigit():
        if int(i) in range(10):
            print "The value of i is %d" % i
        else:
            print "Please enter a valid value"
    else:
        print "This is not a number"
```

As for question 2, the difference between the two is that in the first, `i=input('Enter the value of i')` will be executed before the loop, and in the second it will be executed for each iteration of the loop.  (That is, one time for each time the loop is executed.  Because `range(10)` returns ten items, it runs ten times.)  More about `for` loops [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop), [here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex32.html), and [here](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be having a syntax error because of inconsistent levels of indentation in your code. Please try the following instead and adjust the program to suit whatever your needs might be.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys


def main():
    loop = True
    while loop:
        try:
            i = int(input('Enter of the value of i: '))
        except EOFError:
            sys.exit()
        except ValueError:
            print('This is not a number')
        else:
            if 0 <= i <= 9:
                print('The value of i is', i)
                loop = False
            else:
                print('Please enter a valid value')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```